# Problem with pagelinking when combining amsmath, hyperref and makeidx

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, amsmath, imakeidx

I am preparing a book and have a problem with combining numbering per part (using amsmath package), hyperref and imakeindex.

I have made Indices per Part. In these indices the printed pagenumber references are correct but the link always goes to the corresponding page of the first Part. I couldn't find a solution anywhere, so please help!

The MWE below shows the problem.

```
   \documentclass[12pt]{book}
    
    % Make indices per part
    \usepackage{imakeidx}
    \indexsetup{level=\section*,toclevel=section,noclearpage,firstpagestyle=empty}
     \makeindex[name=subjectsI,title=Subject index Part I,intoc,columns=3, program = truexindy]
      \makeindex[name=subjectsII,title=Subject index Part II,intoc,columns=3, program=truexindy]
    %
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\idxs}[1]{{#1}\index[subjectsI]{#1}}
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\idxsII}[1]{{#1}\index[subjectsII]{#1}}
    %
    %
    % Set spaces for table of contents
    \usepackage{tocloft,xcolor}
    \setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{2.3em}
    \setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{2.5em}
    %
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitV, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=red, urlcolor=black,pageanchor, plainpages=false
    hypertexnames]{hyperref}
    %
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsbsy}
    %
    % numbering chapters and pages per part (uses amsmath)
    \numberwithin{chapter}{part}
    \numberwithin{page}{part}
    \numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
    \numberwithin{table}{chapter}
    %
    
    
    %
    % BOOK
    %
    \begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \tableofcontents
    \cleardoublepage
    %
    %PART I
    %
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \part{This is Part I}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    %
    \chapter{ Chapter one-one}
    \section{Section one-one-one}
    All of us have witnessed how science has profoundly affected  the human condition and transformed society, and how in many instances it managed to transcend man's painful political, ethnic, and \idxs{religious differences}. As such it is a true \idxs{cornerstone} of civilization. 
    %
    \chapter{Chapter one-two}
    \section{Section one-two-one}
    It expresses the \idxs{collective curiosity} of mankind and has resulted in a double helix of science and \idxs{technology} that  keeps transforming our world over and again. 
    \\[2cm]
     
     thepage = \thepage\\
     theHpage = \theHpage
    
     
    %
    %INDICES PART I
    %
    \chapter*{Indices}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Indices}
    \printindex[subjectsI]
    \cleardoublepage
    %
    %PART II
    %
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \part{This is Part II}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    %
    \chapter{Chapter two-one}
    \section{Section two-one-one}
     I go deeper and deeper, as I concentrate on writing, into a kind of \idxsII{underground}. While I'm there, I encounter strange things.
     
    %
    \chapter{Chapter two-two}
    \section{Section two-two-one}
    So I look around that world and I describe what I see, and then I come back. Coming back is important. If you cannot come back, it's scary. But I'm a \idxsII{professional}, so I can come back.
    \\[2cm]
    
     thepage = \thepage\\
     theHpage = \theHpage
    
    %
    %INDICES PART II
    %
    \chapter*{Indices}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Indices}
    \printindex[subjectsII]
    \clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have to ensure that every page has an unique name (that `\thepage` is unique, unlike with other counters `\theHpage` is not used by hyperref), but with all your \pagenumbering commands you are producing e.g. page 1 more than once.

Comment: Yes indeed, thank you Ulrike. But how do I do that? For the link I basically need to use \theHpage and for printing \thepage but I can't figure out how to do that with hyperref.

Comment: there is no `\theHpage` currently, there is no place in the label system to store it (this will perhaps change). So you have to ensure that `\thepage` is unique (and imho it would be good if it were unique in print too, it doesn't make much sense to have ten pages all with number 3. How should the reader find the right one?)

Comment: Thanks again Ulrike. I have a book (>700 pages) that has three parts that will be printed as separate volumes. So the printed version there is no problem. Now this book is going to appear also in. open access as one big pdf, with much cross-referencing. The only problem is this referencing in the Indices as is clear from the MWE. Is there really no way to repair this.

Comment: in the digital version of the LaTeX companion (which has two parts) the printed page numbers in the footer show e.g. 123, but the index, page references and also the page numbers shown at the top of e.g. adobe reader all use `II-123` or `I-123` depending on in which part the page it.